# How to search based on a Multi select category field in Craft 3?

Tags: craft3, search, field, filter, category

I have a blog section with multi select categories. I want to filter all the blogs based on that multi select categories in the website. When I tried

```
 .search('category:ui-ux OR category:web-designs')
```

the result blogs are not accurate.

Category is a multi select field. So multiple category may assigned to one blog. I will list all these categories in my front end and need to filter blogs based on that.

How I will do this search?

Comment: Is the field handle you are trying to search `category`?

Comment: yes , the field handle of the multi select field that I added from admin is 'category'.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering entries based on relationships (categories/assets/users/tags/other entries), you need to use the `relatedTo` parameter, not the `search` parameter.

Here's an example: [Filter based Search Form](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/10321/filter-based-search-form)

Comment: Thank you. Let me check

Comment: can you please advice, what is this `.group('knowledge')` in query?

Comment: That's simply outputting categories from a category group called 'knowledge'. It's not relevant to your question - you just need to use the `relatedTo` parameter instead of the `search` parameter as detailed in that question.

Comment: Thank you. `{% paginate craft.entries.section('blog').relatedTo('category:ui-ux OR category:healthcare').orderBy('postDate desc').limit(10) as pageInfo, entryTemplates %}`  . This not works for me, getting empty results.

Comment: To use the `relatedTo` parameter you need to pass it either the category element(s), or the id(s) of the category/categories. See the docs: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/relations.html#the-relatedto-parameter